# (Conceptual) Continuity of binary relation $\succsim$ and definition using contour sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convergence-divergence, continuity, relations

**Some background information: $\succsim$ is a binary relation that represents preference between two goods. $\succsim$ means "x is at least as good as y." Continuity of this relation is defined to be that if it is preserved in limits: if for any pair of sequences $(x^n,y^n)$ converging to x and y respectively and $x^n\succsim y^n$ $\forall n$, then $x\succsim y$. Also, $x\in\mathbb{R^L_+}$. So, X is a set of possible goods we can choose and these goods are L-vectors.**

I am trying to understand that an equivalent way of stating "a preference relation that is continuous on $X$" is to say "the upper and lower contours sets are closed". What I don't understand is authors in a book says the following:

**The continuity of $\succsim$ on X implies that for any sequence of points $\{y^n\}$ with $x\succsim y^n$ $\forall n$ and $y^n$ converging to $y$, we have $x\succsim y$. And, this implies the lower contour $L(x)=\{y\in X:x\succsim y\}$ set is closed.**

My instinct was to show the lower contour set is closed is equivalent to showing the set contains all its limit points. And how do you do this? Well, in this case, it is to show whether, say the lower contour set, contains its boundary points. These points in collection is just the indifference set $I(x)=\{y\in X:y\sim x\}$.

Then, I want to show $I(x)\subset L(x)$.

***Proof***
: (1) Suppose $x\in I(x)$.

(2) By definition, $x\succsim y$ and $y\succsim x$ $\iff x\sim y$. Hence, $I(x)=\{y\in X:y\succsim x\}\cap\{y\in X:x\succsim y\}$.

(3) Hence, $x\in L(x)$ and $I(x)\subset L(x)$. Q.E.D.

Is my approach incomplete and how should I make sense of MWG's claim above? Please help. Thank you!!

Comment: I believe that this is not true in a general topological space. Did the author make some assumptions about $X$?

Comment: @StanCoreyCarter : Also, $x\in\mathbb{R^L_+}$. So, X is a set of possible goods we can choose and these goods are L-vectors. Sorry, should've included this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Continuity of this relation is defined to be that if it is preserved in limits: if for any pair of sequences $(x^n,y^n)$ converging to x and y respectively and $x^n\succsim y^n$ $\forall n$, then $x\succsim y$.

This statement easily implies

> for any sequence of points $\{y^n\}$ with $x\succsim y^n$ $\forall n$ and $y^n$ converging to $y$, we have $x\succsim y$.

if you fix the constant sequence $x^n=x$ for all $n$. Then note that this statement is equivalent to saying "if $y^n\in L(x)$ and $y_n\to y$, then $y\in L(x)$." You'll see that this is exactly the definition of $L(x)$ being sequentially closed (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space#Definitions)). Thus you know that the statement

> the lower contour $L(x)=\{y\in X:x\succsim y\}$ set is closed.

is definitely true as long as "sequentially closed" implies "closed." But counterintuitively, this is not always the case! Topologies in which this is true are called sequential topologies. You can guarantee you are in one of these if $\mathbb L$ is at most countable since then $\mathbb R^\mathbb L$ will be first countable (see the same Wikipedia page).

Comment: Stan, thanks for the answer. Can you please elaborate the second part when you explained "Note ... sequentially closed."?

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: Stan, thank you for the more elaborate version. While I digest this, how would this be different or similar to the definition of a set is closed IFF it contains all its limit points. This definition is something I learned dealing with the real line.

Comment: The limit point definition is what is meant by saying a set is closed. In most situations, that definition is equivalent to the sequential definition. For example, on metric spaces (like $\mathbb R$) the two are equivalent (which isn't hard to prove). By contrast, if in your example $\mathbb L$ is uncountable, I don't believe the equivalence would hold anymore. Fortunately, most spaces you deal with in analysis and economics are metric spaces so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Stan, this is a silly question but I am compelled to ask cause I am confused. The set $L(x)=\{y\in X:x\succsim y\}$ is called lower contour set, which is basically a lower half under the indifference curve in the cartesian plane in $\mathbb{R^2_+}$ when we only consider two goods. My question is shouldn't the argument in the set be y such that $L(y)=\{y\in X:x\succsim y\}$ not x? I am confused about the set notation.

Comment: No, when you write $\{y:\cdots\}$, $y$ is a dummy variable so it doesn't make sense outside of the curly brackets. Think of $L(x)$ as the set of things that $x$ is preferred to.

Comment: Stan, thanks for the comment. It makes sense. I actually looked at this on real line and treated the relation as the good old inequality, and it makes a perfect sense.